# How can I aggregate values in one column based on the lookup values in another sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I am looking for a way to aggregate the values in one sheet based on groupings that can be found on another sheet. Please see example below:

Essentially, each region has several IDs and I am trying to aggregate sales on a region level (Sheet 3). Unfortunately the data source (Sheet 1) only contains IDs, but I have a lookup table (Sheet 2) which groups all IDs by their region.

[image]

What I have tried is to create hidden columns to the right of the report that contain IDs for each region, which I use for a SUMPRODUCT + SUMIF formula to reference both Sheet 1 and 2. It works, but I am wondering if there is a simpler way that doesn't require me to create hidden columns.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS($B$3:$B$9,$A$3:$A$9,$D$3:$D$9)*($E$3:$E$9=G2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, this works. But I am wondering if you have time to explain the function's components. I don't really get the criteria you put into the SUMIFS function. Thanks again.

Comment: it creates two arrays one of the sum and another of 1s and 0s and multiplies them together.  By putting a range in the criteria it returns an array.